# Restrict users from editing post based on the age of the post

Tags: php, wordpress, restrict, capability

In Wordpress, how can I restrict users (based on [Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)) from editing their published posts after a custom amount of time.

For instance, a user that can `publish_posts` (authors) can **not** edit a their post if it is older than 3 days, and a user that can `moderate_comments` (editors) can not edit any posts that are older than 20 days. Obviously, admins can edit anytime.

How is such thing possible?

Comment: Or alternatively, the posts gets locked from editing after a custom amount of time.

Comment: duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69577/restrict-users-from-editing-post-based-on-the-age-of-the-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the duplicate of [a question on wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69577/restrict-users-from-editing-post-based-on-the-age-of-the-post).  I've copied my answer below.

> I took the example code from the Wordpress [user_has_cap filter codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_has_cap) and modified it.  Add this code to your theme functions.php:
>
> ```
> function restrict_editing_old_posts( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {
>
>   // Bail out if we're not asking to edit a post ...
>   if( 'edit_post' != $args[0]
>     // ... or user is admin
>     || ! empty( $allcaps['manage_options'] )
>     // ... or user already cannot edit the post
>     || empty( $allcaps['edit_posts'] ) )
>       return $allcaps;
>
>   // Load the post data:  
>   $post = get_post( $args[2] );
>
>   // Bail out if the post isn't published:    
>   if( 'publish' != $post->post_status )
>       return $allcaps;
>
>   $post_date = strtotime( $post->post_date );
>   //if post is older than 30 days ... 
>   if( $post_date < strtotime( '-30 days' )
>     // ... or if older than 4 days and user is not Editor
>     || ( empty($allcaps['moderate_comments']) 
>     && $post_date < strtotime('-4 days') ) ) {
>       $allcaps[$cap[0]] = FALSE;  
>   }
>   return $allcaps;
> }
> add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'restrict_editing_old_posts', 10, 3 );
> ```

Answer (score -1):

This should work inside a plugin

```
    function remove_edit() {

    // Adjust 604800 to the number of days in seconds that you want to check against. Posts will only appear if they are newer than that time.//
     if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && (current_user_can('edit_posts') && ((current_time(timestamp) - get_the_time('U') - (get_settings('gmt_offset') * 3600) ) < 604800) )
     {
        unset( $actions['edit'] );
     }
   }
   add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_edit',10,1);
```

From wordpress codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_posts

```
edit_posts
  Since 2.0
  Allows access to Administration Panel options:
   Posts
   Posts > Add New
   Comments
   Comments > Awaiting Moderation
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how this code works? As far as I can tell, there is no way to set which users this applies to? How do I add capabilities in this...?

Comment: check tis function in the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can.

Comment: Excellent, just one final question: no matter what I set it to, Admins will always be affected. Let me explain, if I set the capability to **publish_posts**, then authors to admins will be affected by it... meaning that admins will be locked from editing posts as much as authors do. Do you understand the problem here?

Comment: added condition to ignore admins

Comment: Perfect, I was not aware that was possible. Final question if you do not mind, can I execute this script through the functions.php or do I need add it in a custom plugin?

Comment: I added your code to function.php and received an error. I am sure it must be a typo in your code? Here is the error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'**

Comment: Can you kindly test your code in Wordpress and confirm if it functions as proposed?

Comment: @Udan I would like to know this as well. Is this working? Have you tried it Udan?

Comment: This code would **only hide the LINK to edit** in the Dashboard post list.  In other words, users with permission could still edit a post if they get ahold of the edit link.  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938514/restrict-users-from-editing-post-based-on-the-age-of-the-post/12978067#12978067) to prevent all attempts to edit as well as hide links.